# PHP : Not able to call static method in another class

Tags: php, oop

I have a made a database connection script as follows :

```
class DBManager{
static $connection;
public $dbh;
private $dbHost = null, $dbUser = null, $dbPass = null, $dbName= null;

private function __construct($dbDetails = array()){
    $this->dbHost = $dbDetails['db_host'];
    $this->dbName = $dbDetails['db_name'];
    $this->dbUser = $dbDetails['db_user'];
    $this->dbPass = $dbDetails['db_pass'];

    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHost;dbname = $this->dbName", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
}

public static function init($dbDetails){
    if(isset(self::$connection)){
        return self::$connection;
    }
    else{
        return self::$connection = new DBManager($dbDetails);
    }
}
}

$dbDetails = array(
'db_host' => '127.0.0.1',
'db_name' => 'loura',
'db_user' => 'root',
'db_pass' => ''
);
```

and I want to get the connection in my other class by doing:

```
require_once('test.php');

class Data{

private $dbh;

public function __construct($dbDetails){
    $this->dbh = DBManager::init($dbDetails);
}

function getInfo(){
    $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_master");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchAll();

}
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? I am trying to call a static method in another class, is that legal?

EDIT: this is my error:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DBManager::prepare()

Comment: First you have to call first call into second by using "required" or "include"

Comment: Your error is quite clear, ensure the correct variable(s) are being passed to your class constructor.

Comment: As @AmanKumar wrote, You must import your class into this file. With include/require or using namespaces.

Comment: @Script47 But what else can I pass through the function I dont have any other parameters.

Comment: @IrfanSindhi have you passed the `$dbDetails` parameter?

Comment: An another question: are You making an instance of class Data elswhere? Error msg says that you aren't passing enough arguments to it's constructor... You must do it like $data = new Data($dbDetails); $data->getInfo();

Comment: $this->dbh = DBManager::init($this->dbDetails); instead, try following $this->dbh = DBManager::init($dbDetails);

Comment: @tan I did that , now it gives me the error : Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DBManager::prepare()

Comment: @IgorW. Yes I have done that

Comment: There is no method prepare() in your DBManager class! $this->dbh->dbh->prepare() might work. Please note "dbh->dbh"

Comment: @tan my fetchAll gives me a blank array

Comment: @IrfanSindhi Show us the code where you use this class. But with namespace usage or require.

Comment: @IgorW. How do I give a namespace , I have just included my class with require_once. Check my `required_once ` in my updated answer.

Comment: @IrfanSindhi http://php.net/language.namespaces - about namespaces

Comment: @IrfanSindhi File with class DBManager should contain only this class. And it should have name DBManager.php, not test.php. This is why i tought you don't make require...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest something like this.

```
// DBConfig.php
namespace App\Model\Db;

class DBConfig {
    public static $dbConfig = [
        'db_host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'db_name' => 'loura',
        'db_user' => 'root',
        'db_pass' => '',
    ];
}

// DBConnection.php
namespace App\Model\Db;

class DBConnection {
    private $dbh = null;
    private $dbHost = null, $dbUser = null, $dbPass = null, $dbName= null;

    public function getDbh()
    {
        return $this->dbh;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up connection on class create.
     */
    public function __construct($dbDetails = array()){
        $this->dbHost = $dbDetails['db_host'];
        $this->dbName = $dbDetails['db_name'];
        $this->dbUser = $dbDetails['db_user'];
        $this->dbPass = $dbDetails['db_pass'];

        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHost;dbname = $this->dbName", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
   }
}

// DBManager.php
namespace App\Model\Db;

class DBManager {
    private $connection = null;

    public static getConnection()
    {
        if ($this->connection instanceof DBConnection) {
            return $this->connection;
        } else {
            $this-connection = new DBConnection(DBConfig::dbConfig);

            return $this->connection;
        }
    }
}

// Data.php
namespace App\Model\Data;

use App\Model\DBManager;

class Data {
    function getInfo(){
        $conn = DBManager::getConnection();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_master");
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have type polymorphism problem in class DBManager:

```
public static function init($dbDetails){

    if(isset(self::$connection)){

        // here is new mysqli()? connection
        return self::$connection;
    }
    else{
        /*
         here is NOT - just a DBManager instance

         return self::$connection = new DBManager($dbDetails);
         instead you should do something like:
        */
        return self::$connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on `return self::$connection = new DBManager($dbDetails);`, what is returned here is `DBManager` instance, not a `PDO` instance.

```
class DBManager{
static $connection;
public $dbh;
private $dbHost = null, $dbUser = null, $dbPass = null, $dbName= null;

private function __construct($dbDetails = array()){
    $this->dbHost = $dbDetails['db_host'];
    $this->dbName = $dbDetails['db_name'];
    $this->dbUser = $dbDetails['db_user'];
    $this->dbPass = $dbDetails['db_pass'];

    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->dbHost;dbname = $this->dbName", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
}

public static function init($dbDetails){
    if(isset(self::$connection)){
        return self::$connection;
    }
    else{
        self::$connection = new self($dbDetails);
        return self::$connection->dbh;
    }
}
}
```

But I suggest using the following `class`

```
/**
 * PDO database, only one connection is allowed.
 *
 */
class Db {

    //
    private $_dbh;

    // Store the single instance.
    private static $_instance;

    /**
     *  Get an instance of the database.
     *  @return Db.
     */
    public static function instance(){
        if( !self::$_instance ){
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_instance->_dbh;
    }

    /**
     * Magic __construct.
     */
    function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME.";charset=".DB_CHARSET, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD );
        }catch( PDOException $e ){
            trigger_error( $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL, E_USER_ERROR );
            die( 'Error: Can\'t connect to the database.' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Empty clone method to prevent duplication.
     */
    function __clone(){}
}
```